# iphone memory over release

Tags: iphone, objective-c

if I release a variable more than it should be, would that be a problem? I cannot determine the retain count ahead of time.

Comment: You should always be able to determine how many times your code has incremented the reference count.  Post your code here if you're having trouble doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Foreword

The retain count should be considered more of a theoretical offset. You should never care about what the value currently is, just how your actions will offset it. For example, when you add an object to an array, you have offset its retain count by +1, and when you remove an object from an array, you have offset its retain count by −1. When you're completely done with an object, its retain count offset (relative to you) should be 0. What its retain count *actually* is does not matter, as long as you fulfil your obligations to manage the object appropriately.

Inspecting the retain count explicitly will often not show what you expect. This could be because of optimisations under the hood. Cocoa relies on the developer conforming to the [memory management guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/memorymgmt.html). Follow these very simple rules, and do not worry about the explicit value of `retainCount`.

#### WRT the question

Over-releasing an object (sending it too many release messages) can—and usually does—result in premature deallocation of that object. Any messages that get sent to the address where the deallocated object used to be will usually crash your application. The dumbed-down rules of thumb are:

1. Sending a `alloc`, `new`, `retain`, `copy` (or any method with `copy` in its name) will give you an object with a retain count offset by +1.
2. Sending `release` will offset that objects retain count by −1.
3. Balance each +1 with a −1 and that's it!

#### Furthermore

If you are developing a framework or library and you are returning objects to users of your framework, don't try to prevent errors in their code by over-retaining objects. Their obligations are exactly the same as yours, and if they break your framework from poor memory management then that is a bug in *their* code, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the `retainCount`. Only send release to an object that you own. If you get an object by sending `alloc` to a class, or send an object a `retain`, `copy` or `mutableCopy` message,  then you own the object and are responsible for sending it a `release` message at some time in the future.

It's all explained in the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/memorymgmt.html).

Comment: let's say i have one alloc but released twice. would that be a problem?

Comment: You never release twice for an object that you alloc once.  The `retainCount` won't always match how many times you alloc'd it since there are things going on in the OS background that might retain the object for its own use.  **Only** release it once if you retained or alloc'd it once.

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem. It may not cause a crash straight away, but it will cause a crash sometime in the future and will be very tricky to track down if you do it inadvertently.

Comment: I think the question is; why would you release it a second time?

Comment: it might be released a second time. depending on how the user uses it

Comment: If you have a code path where an object may be released a second time, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: `init` doesn't increase a retain count, only `alloc` does, otherwise `[[Class alloc] init]` pairs would have +2 retain count.

Comment: so if I init an object multiple times. I only need to release it once?

Comment: @Yazzmi: In theory yes, but, you should never `init` an object more than once. I was only stating that it is `alloc` that causes the +1, not `init`.

Answer (score 0):

Please please please do not over release an object ever.

While you're developing your app, it's wise to set the environment variable

MallocScribble="YES"

This will immediately overwrite the pointer for a free'd object to 0x555 so you'll crash where you wouldn't before.  Also break on obj-c exceptions!  These two settings enabled will help make your app more robust.

Comment: MallocScribble and what's the other variable? These are Xcode settings right? and make the debugger more sensitive?